# "diciannovesimo" vs. "decimonono" vs. "nonodecimo"

Tags: adjectives, numbers

Qual è la differenza tra questi aggettivi numerali, usati per indicare un numero ordinale? Ovvero, quali sono le migliori indicazioni d'uso (quando usare una forma, e quando un'altra)?

Comment: Normally you would use "diciannovesimo"; you can use "decimonono" in books of history. "Nonodecimo" is rare, you are not supposed to use it if you live in the 21st century.

Comment: Mai sentito 'nonodecimo'. 'Decimonono' si usa tipicamente solo in riferimento a nomi di monarchi/papi etc.

Comment: @martina [nonodecimo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nonodecimo/) is ok, but rare. Both "decimonono" and "nonodecimo" are used for centuries as well as for names.

Comment: The only current use of "decimonono" AFAIK is for the [newspaper](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il_Secolo_XIX).

Comment: @MatteoItalia, it can also be used for pope Giovanni XIX. I should add that I have never heard _nonodecimo_, but often _undecimo_ and _duodecimo_. The rationale is: un+dici⇒un+decimo, dicia+n+nove⇒decimo+nono

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Era un sistema comune nell'Ottocento, adesso ormai completamente abbandonato. Cito dal [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/aggettivi-numerali-ordinali_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/), a cui rimando per ulteriori informazioni:

> In riferimento ai secoli o al nome di sovrani e pontefici, talvolta si usa ancora (per i numeri superiori al decimo) il sistema di conteggio comune fino all’Ottocento, che consiste nel tenere separato l’aggettivo indicante la prima cifra da quello indicante la seconda (decimoprimo invece di undicesimo; ventesimoquinto invece di venticinquesimo).

Oggigiorno è sempre preferibile l'utilizzo del suffisso sulla cifra complessiva, per esempio diacannovesimo.

Comment: aggiungo che papa Giovanni XXIII, oltre che ventitreesimo, era anche detto *vigesimo*terzo, non *ventesimo*terzo

Comment: @mau Spero che “ventesimo terzo” non sia mai stato scritto: o si segue la versione “latina” o quella “italiana”, una via di mezzo sarebbe davvero orribile.

Comment: @egreg io non ho mai visto "ventesimoterzo", ma tutto è possibile...

Comment: Vicino a dove abito c'è piazza Pio XI, che ho sentito chiamare sia _undecimo_ che _undicesimo_, direi in parti uguali. Io personalmente mi attengo a _undecimo_, che è, tra i due, quello con cui sono venuto in contatto prima.

Comment: @Wakter Tross è una forma arcaica che deriva dal latino non penso che sia molto utilizzata...